# How can I convert spark dataframe to csv error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I try to make spark dataframe using sql.
In my code, I think that making spark dataframe with sql succeeded because when I check type of "result" by "type(result)" it has spark dataframe type.
The problem is "result.write.csv("./result")"
When I try to do it, the following error appeared.
How can I fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krX4f.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import pyspark.pandas as ps
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row

# spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Pyspark Read Parquet").getOrCreate()

# Read parquet
path = "./data/fhvhv_tripdata_2022-01.parquet"
parquet_df = spark.read.parquet(path)

# name table
parquet_df.createOrReplaceTempView("ParquetTable")

# query for spend_time related to trip_miles
query = """SELECT on_scene_datetime, request_datetime, (on_scene_datetime - request_datetime) as spend_time, trip_miles, sales_tax
           FROM ParquetTable
           WHERE on_scene_datetime IS NOT NULL AND
           request_datetime IS NOT NULL AND
           INT(on_scene_datetime - request_datetime) > 0
           ORDER BY 4 DESC"""
result = spark.sql(query)
result.show(3, truncate = False)

result.write.csv("./result")
```

Comment: are you writing the final df into local disc or any other storage(hdfs or s3)

Comment: Hadoop doesnt have a concept of current dir (`.`). Perhaps you can try to supply an absolute path?

Comment: I write the fianl df into local disc.

Comment: I tried to make dir "/result" but, it was also the same

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the following:

- The path where you want to write the CSV exists (all folders and subfolders)
- In your code, provide the full path where you want to write the CSV (not only `./result`). For example, `C:/MyFolder/MySubfolder/results/`
- Make sure that it's a path, i.e. it ends with `/`

**NOTE**
I can't remember now if you will need to specify the path with `/` or `\`.
If `\`, make sure to double it, cause it's a special char and must be escaped in strings.

**OBSERVATION**
If you're going to write some unit tests, I suggest importing `java.nio.file.Files`. You'll be looking for `Files.createTempDirectory`, which creates a temp folder and for you and automatically make sure that whatever you put in there gets deleted at the end of the test. For example (from Scala), `val targetTestPath = Files.createTempDirectory("TestDirectory").toString`

Answer (score 0):

Is there any more to the error message?

The main thing that occurs to me is to try writing to `./result/`

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'
... error occured. but I didn't capture the extra error because I think it is not meaningful